# Redux and socket.io infinite loop

Tags: redux, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to use [socket.io](https://socket.io/) and [redux-socket.io](https://github.com/itaylor/redux-socket.io) to simply keep data stores in sync for mutliple clients.

Each client will FETCH their own initial list of "todos" which will be put into their redux store.

Then when a client performs and ADD, UPDATE, or DELETE, I want it broadcast to the other clients to update their own redux store; here's what I have -

**client setup**

```
let socketIoMiddleware = createSocketIoMiddleware(socket, (type, action) => {
  // emit to server if one of these actions
  return (type === 'ADD_TODO_SUCCESS' || 
    type === 'UPDATE_TODO_SUCCESS' ||
    type === 'DELETE_TODO_SUCCESS')
});
```

**server**

```
socket.on('action', (action) => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('action', action);
    }
}
```

My goal was to not have to change my redux code and just plug socket.io in, but what I think is happening is, for ex:

1. Client A: `dispatch({type: 'UPDATE_TODO_SUCESS', payload: todo });`
2. middleware: `emit('action', {type: 'UPDATE_TODO_SUCESS', payload: todo });`
3. socket.io server: `broadcast('action', {type: 'UPDATE_TODO_SUCESS', payload: todo });`
4. Client B: `on('action', dispatch({type: 'UPDATE_TODO_SUCESS', payload: todo });`
5. middleware: `emit('action', {type: 'UPDATE_TODO_SUCESS', payload: todo });`
6. ... inifinite loop!

How can I broadcast updates to other clients without causing this infinite loop and without having to handle a bunch of other action types in my reducers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with is to augment the action objects with a boolean `broadcast` property that is used to decide if the redux-socket.io should emit the message to the server.

The [second parameter of createSocketIoMiddleware](https://github.com/itaylor/redux-socket.io#allowed-criteria-for-action-matching) can be *"...a function that returns a truthy value if the action should be sent to socket.io"*

**client setup**

```
let socketIoMiddleware = createSocketIoMiddleware(socket, (type, action) => {
  // emit to server if action has property "broadcast: true"
  return action.broadcast;
});
```

**example action:**

```
const addTodo = todo => {
   return {
      type: 'ADD_TODO_SUCCESS,
      todo: todo,
      broadcast: true
   };
};
```

**server setup**

```
socket.on('action', (action) => {
   // turn broadcast off so subscriber doesn't turn around and publish
   if(action.broadcast) {
      action.broadcast = false;
   }
   socket.broadcast.emit('action', action);
 }
}
```